# IIS Restart Excel Web Services

Tags: sharepoint, excel, iis, service

I am trying to investigate the effects of restarting an IIS when I am programatically doing manipulations using Excel Web Services. My investigation has revealed that restarting the IIS while the program is in session seems to cause the program to blow up.

Also, we tried restarting the sharepoint excel services app pool. This does not cause our application to blow up.

I am just interested in knowing how the excel services is architected to handle these kind of scenarios's and if my inferences about restarting the IIS and the app pool is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more information about your application and what do you mean by "blow up"?

But in general, the ECS keeps state about your workbook in memory therefore if you restart the service your session and workbook in memory will no longer be available. In other words if you send a request against a specific session id, this one will no longer exists and therefore will fail. You'll have to reopen a new session but not knowing more specifics about your application I can't know for sure what's happening.